# How return substring of url path in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

I have this url

```
www.testing.com/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination.topage/2?t:ac=3686975/4441810
```

and i want to have **2**

i tried this in python 2.7:

```
s = 'www.testing.com/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination.topage/2?t:ac=3686975/4441810'
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("topage/") + 1);
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("?"));
print s
```

and i got this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'substring'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
s = 'www.testing.com/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination.topage/2?t:ac=3686975/4441810'
    s =     s[:s.index("?")]
    s = s[-1:]
    print s
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse) function if you need different component of an URL.

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> u = urlparse("www.testing.com/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination.topage/2?t:ac=3686975/4441810")
>>> u
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='www.testing.com/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination.topage/2', params='', query='t:ac=3686975/4441810', fragment='')
>>> u.path[-1]
'2'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [62]:  s = 'www.testing.com/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination.topage/2?t:ac=3686975/4441810'

In [63]: s[s.index("topage/")+ len('toppage'):s.index("?")]
Out[63]: '2
```